# How do I use DotNetOpenAuth to setup an openId login programmatically, not in MVC or ASP forms

Tags: wpf, winforms, openid, dotnetopenauth

I've previously used dotnetopenauth to enable a web app to be an OpenId relaying party.

However, I'd like to enable a winforms or WPF app to do the same, using the WebBrowser control.

I know that I need to set up the process first with the provider (who will be Google, or my own provider which already exists). However, the documentation and examples all refer to OpenIdRelyingParty.CreateRequest(), but in the latest version that method does not exist and instead there is 'CreateRequestAsync'. Worse, this requires a 'Identifier userSuppliedIdentifier' which is precisely the information I want, not what I should be supplying when the provider is already known.

I would then use the WebBrowser control to get the user to visit the provider's page and use the Navigating event on the browser control to capture a fake returnUrl.

Can I do what I want using DotNetOpenAuth? Or does it use magic specifically tied to certain web frameworks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you might be using the pre-release version of DNOA, try downgrading to the latest stable version which is 4.3.4.13329.

Comment: @Robin I'm facing the same issue, trying to implement OAuth v1 with OpenID in a Winform application. Did that version 4.3 work for you? Do you have a sample implementation by any chance? I had downloaded the v5 of DNOA and I saw the same issues.

Comment: @ThomasJaeger yes this fixed the issue for me. I should have marked the answer in a timely fashion! If you can't get it to work I'll privately email a snippet. robin at rbanderson co uk.